# Include file oddity in ui_mainwindow.h

Tags: qt, qt-creator

In my app I have an oddity in the ui_mainwindow.h file include section.  This is what the last four lines of the includes looks like

```
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include <treeviewview.h>
#include "logo.h"
#include "partslistview.h"
```

As you can see the first line references a Qt library file ok.  The second line is one of my files, yet it has the angle brackets round it.  The thrid and last lines are mine and are included properly.

treeviewview.h contains a subclass of a QTreeView.  I drop a tree view on the main window and promote it to my treeviewview.  I do the same with partslistview, but that is based on a QTableView. It gets promoted in Qt-creator in the same way as the treeview.

The problem that I am having is that I have just added a new signal into the real treeviewview.h file.  I have a connect statement that connects it to a slot.  When run I get an error "No such signal: TreeViewView::NewSlot(QString, QString)"

But it is declared in the real header file right next to another older signal that connects properly in the line before the new connect line.

I think the error is somehow is  related to the odd inclusion in the ui header file.

Whether this is the cause of the signal connection problem, it needs sorting.

If I open the treeviewview.h file that ui_mainwindow.h is pointing to, it exists and contains code for an empty class.

As ui_mainwindow.h is a Qt generated file, how do I sort this?

Secondly, how did this happen, so I can avoid doing it again?

Comment: Concerning the angle brackets, you may have checked "global header"  when adding the treeviewview class header.

Comment: Thanks, Frodon, it wasn't deliberate if I did. Is there a way to undo that?

Comment: Remove and add again the class ?

Comment: You probably can edit that property in .ui file manually. But I doubt this has any effect on your problem.

Comment: Thanks Pavel.  I opened the mainwindow.ui file in Notepad++ and found a "location global" indicator in the xml.  I edited that and now a clean and build results in the include section being correct.  Thank you.

Comment: The other issue I was having where the compiler wasn't finding methods declared in treeviewview.h was that there was .h and .cpp files in the build folder.  Deleting those files fixed that.